# How can I sort a TCL array based on the values of its keys?

Tags: arrays, sorting, tcl

The `INITIAL_ARRAY` is

```
Key -> Value
B      8
C     10
A      5
E      3
D      1
```

To get a sorted array based on key,  I use

```
set sorted_keys_array [lsort [array names INITIAL_ARRAY]]
```

to get the output

```
Key -> Value
A     5
B     8
C     10
D     1
E     3
```

Like wise, how to get a sorted  tcl array based on **values** of keys, like output  below?

```
Key -> Value
 C     10
 B     8 
 A     5
 E     3
 D     1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with Tcl 8.6, you could do

```
lsort -stride 2 -integer [array get a]
```

which would produce a *flat* list of key/value pairs sorted on values.

Before `lsort` gained the `-stride` option, you had to resort to constructing a list of lists out of the flat list `array get` returns and then sort it using the `-index` option for `lsort`:

```
set x [list]
foreach {k v} [array get a] {
    lappend x [list $k $v]
}
lsort -integer -index 1 $x
```

Comment: The last line should be replaced by
    **set result [lsort -integer -index 1 $x]**
since "lsort" produces new list rather than changes existing one.

Comment: @mkostya, I demonstrated the idea, not a complete program. Moreover, there are legitimate cases to just use the return value of a command without assigning it to a variable -- for instance, you could wrap a `proc` body around the second example, and that proc would return whatever `lsort` returns.

Answer (score 3):

The previous methods on this didn't work for me, when I have an array:

```
[array get a] == D 1 E 3 A 5 B 8 C 10
```

I do a the following and receive the error:

```
lsort -stride 2 -integer [array get a]
```

> expected integer but got "D"

You need to also add in an index:

```
lsort -integer -stride 2 -index 1 [array get a]
```

> D 1 C 10 E 3 A 5 B 8

And then you can change the direction:

```
lsort -decreasing -integer -stride 2 -index 1 [array get a]
```

> C 10 B 8 A 5 E 3 D 1

Which then gives the correct answer