# How to sort with TCL from given file?

Tags: tcl

I am having trouble in sorting with TCL, I am not able fit reference example into mine.

I have file which contains two columns, `name` & `area`, how to sort by area without changing respective name?

I am trying with foreach & associate array but so far I am not able to do so...

```
LSDNENCLSSXl_HVT    2.2872
LSDNENCLSSX2_HVT    2.5414
LSDNENCLSSX4_HVT    3.0497
LSDNENCLSSX8_HVT    4.0663
LSDNENCLX1_HVT  7.116032
LSDNENCLX2_HVT  7.62432
LSDNENCLX4_HVT  8.640896
LSDNENCLX8_HVT  11.18233
LSDNENSSXl_HVT  4.320448
LSDNENSSX2_HVT  5.08288
LSDNENSSX4_HVT  5.591168
LSDNENSSX8_HVT  7.370176
LSDNENXl_HVT    7.116032
LSDNENX2_HVT    7.62432
LSDNENX4_HVT    8.640896
LSDNENX8_HVT    11.182336
LSDNSSXl_HVT    1.779008
LSDNSSX2_HVT    2.033152
LSDNSSX4_HVT    2.54144
LSDNSSX8_HVT    4.320448
LSDNXl_HVT  7.116032
LSDNX2_HVT  7.116032
LSDNX4_HVT  7.116032
LSDNX8_HVT  9.149184
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Posting images instead of text is not very useful.  What have you tried so far?  Essentially you have to split apart the data on the colons, creating a list, sort the list and then put the data back together.

Comment: Try to solve this problem piece by piece. Open the file in read mode, read all text in a string, split this string by `\n`, loop over each line, split the line by space, store the first column as key and second column as value in a tcl array. Then see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14769783/252489. If you get into problems, show us the code.

Comment: set fh [open "result_table_sort" r]
set data [read $fh]
close $fh

foreach {name area} [array get $data] {
  lappend $data [list $name $area]
}
set result [lsort -integer -index 1 $data]
puts $result


The foloowing error is generated:
element 1 missing from sublist "LSDNENCLSSX1_HVT"
    while executing
"lsort -integer -index 1 $data"
    invoked from within
"set result [lsort -integer -index 1 $data]"
    (file "sort.tcl" line 16)

Answer (score 0):

```
set fh [open "filename"]
set data [read $fh]
close $fh
set words [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $data]

foreach {name area} [lsort -stride 2 -index 1 -real $words] {
    puts "$name\t$area"
}
```

See [`lsort`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.htm) documentation.

Output

```
LSDNSSXl_HVT    1.779008
LSDNSSX2_HVT    2.033152
LSDNENCLSSXl_HVT    2.2872
LSDNENCLSSX2_HVT    2.5414
LSDNSSX4_HVT    2.54144
LSDNENCLSSX4_HVT    3.0497
LSDNENCLSSX8_HVT    4.0663
LSDNENSSXl_HVT  4.320448
LSDNSSX8_HVT    4.320448
LSDNENSSX2_HVT  5.08288
LSDNENSSX4_HVT  5.591168
LSDNENCLX1_HVT  7.116032
LSDNENXl_HVT    7.116032
LSDNXl_HVT  7.116032
LSDNX2_HVT  7.116032
LSDNX4_HVT  7.116032
LSDNENSSX8_HVT  7.370176
LSDNENCLX2_HVT  7.62432
LSDNENX2_HVT    7.62432
LSDNENCLX4_HVT  8.640896
LSDNENX4_HVT    8.640896
LSDNX8_HVT  9.149184
LSDNENCLX8_HVT  11.18233
LSDNENX8_HVT    11.182336
```

Comment: bad option "-stride": must be -ascii, -command, -decreasing, -dictionary, -increasing, -index, -integer, -real, or -unique
    while executing
"lsort -stride 2 -index 1 -integer $words"
    invoked from within
"foreach  {name area} [lsort -stride 2 -index 1 -integer $words] {
puts "$name \t$area"
}"
    (file "sort.tcl" line 9)

Answer (score 0):

`-stride` is a feature added in Tcl 8.6, so I guess you are using Tcl 8.5 or earlier.

Also, the code in your comment doesn't quite look right. There are a couple of things that look wrong. You need to pass a list to `array set` to get an array and arrays are not sorted, so I would drop that altogether. I would suggest something like that:

```
set fh [open "result_table_sort" r]
set data [read $fh]
close $fh
set lines [split $data "\n"]               ;# Use the appropriate EOL character
                                            # if it's different
set result [lsort -real -index 1 $lines]
puts $result
```

The above assumes that the file `result_table_sort` is well structured and doesn't contain anything not formatted/structured as described in the sample provided.

Comment: I am able to trim null character with string trim... Thnaks

Comment: @CLEX420 I'm not sure what you mean. Is it with reference to EOL? EOL = End Of Line. Windows typically uses `\r\n` while linux typically uses `\n`. `\n` stands for line feed character, `\r` stands for carriage return character. When you press the return button, either or a combination of those two characters get inserted to give multiple lines. I am splitting on that character to split the whole file contents into individual lines.

Comment: What you said is correct about splitting, but what i found is: In perl we trim the new line when perl reads file, somehow similar thing that created {}-null string to EOL when we split into individual lines.

Comment: @CLEX420 Are you still talking about your problem of sorting the file? I can't see the relationship between what you are saying and the problem.

Comment: sorting problem has been solved, thanks to feedback from you guys.

Comment: @CLEX420 Would you please mark the answer that suited you the most as accepted? It will also mark your question as resolved :)